# Terminology for "factors other than $1$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, terminology, factoring

I know of the following terms:

- *A proper factor* of a positive integer $n$ is a factor of $n$ other than $1$ or $n$.
- *A proper divisor* of a positive integer $n$ is a factor of $n$ other than $n$ (but including $1$).

But is there a known or used term for the following?

- _____  of a positive integer $n$ is a factor of $n$ other than $1$ (but including $n$).

Or anything similar that can substitute "factors of $n$ other than $1$" ?

For example, say the term "_____" was "*whole factor*".

Then,  I would be able to write "partitions of numbers into *whole factor*s".

For example, all such partitions of $30$ are $30 = 15\cdot2 = 10\cdot3 = 6\cdot5 = 2\cdot3\cdot5$.

But instead of inventing my own word for it such as the above example, I would prefer if there was already an established definition already being used in some context or topics.

**Edit:** After some discussion in the comments, it appears that "[Unordered Factorization](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnorderedFactorization.html)" does not include the factor $1$ by its definition and fits the context in my earlier examples. (*In case this is useful for someone that could have a similar question as me in the future.*)

Comment: I'd suggest "non-unital", but I don't know how widely accepted that is.

Comment: I would say "factors greater than 1", but I think you also have an issue with "partition" which I would usually assume was addition rather than multiplication, so $30=15+15=15+10+5=\cdots$

Comment: @Henry Would you rather say "decomposition" than "partition", in the context of the mentioned example, or something else? (I was thinking about the "partition" of the set of "non-unital" factors)

Comment: Since $1$ is considered a unit, in a class by itself, you could say "prime or composite" factors (or divisors).

Comment: Right... rather than "partitions," I would instead suggest "*factorizations*."  It is unclear what your end goal is with this, whether you are trying to count the number of unique factorizations of a number into nontrivial factors (*unique up to order and sign*), or something else.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm looking at all the factorizations that do not include $1$, and then for example observing the sums of those factorizations. For example, multiples of $4$ cannot have all distinct sums because of the $2+2=2\cdot 2$ equation. And similar properties.

Comment: If you *are* after the count of the number of unique up to order and sign factorizations of $n$ into nontrivial factors, then see http://oeis.org/A074206 and try searching for "Kalmar's Problem"

Comment: @JMoravitz You mentioned/linked "ordered factorization". It appears that "[Unordered Factorization](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnorderedFactorization.html)" does not include the factor $1$ by definition and fits my examples. Thank you.

Comment: @Henry Btw, there is also "multiplicative partition function" that counts unordered factorizations (such factorizations do not contain 1 as a factor). I don't know, I think "(multiplicative) partition" is not uncommon in such context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about *nontrivial* factor?

On this [Massey University site](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/HCFandLCM/FactMult.htm), for example, they define a *trivial* factor of $n$ to be $1$, and an *improper* factor to be $n$ itself.

Some sources use *trivial* to refer to both $1$ and $n$, so whatever term you use, it would be best to make your definition explicit.

Comment: That sounds clear and simple enough.